# iPhone - switching a view controller in the tabbar and call a method

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, delegates

I have a TabBar in my application and I do this in my AppDelegate:

```
...
test2ViewController = [[Test1ViewController alloc] init];
...
navigationTest2Controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:test2ViewController];

NSArray *myControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:..., navigationTest2Controller, nil];
[self.myTabBarController setViewControllers:myControllers animated:NO];
```

Now I have the problem that I am in a ViewController and I want to switch to the "navigationTest2Controller". I do this in my AppDelegate with:

```
self.myTabBarController.selectedViewController = navigationTest2Controller;
```

This works. It switches to this ViewController! This ViewController was already loaded and the viewDidLoad method was called. In this viewDidLoad method is a methos call:

```
[self myMethod];
```

I want, that if the view switches to this ViewController this "myMethod" should always be called.
How can I do this? In my AppDelegate before the line

```
self.myTabBarController.selectedViewController = navigationTest2Controller;
```

??? Or is there another delegate which will be called every time the ViewController is selected/switched to?

Does anyone know this?

Thanks a lot in advance & Best Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should place any code that you want to run when the view becomes visible in the [`-viewWillAppear:`](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillAppear:) or [`-viewDidAppear`](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidAppear:) method of your view controller.

**EDIT:** To make this happen *only* when you switch from a certain view, you can subclass `UITabBarController`, only modifying the [`–tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITabBarControllerDelegate/tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:) method. In that method, you could do something like this:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController
shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if (self.selectedIndex == 1 &&
        [viewController respondsToSelector:@selector(myMethod)]) {
        [viewController myMethod];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: But I only want to call this "myMethod" if I switch from the specific ViewController to this one. All other times, this method should not be called.

Comment: Tim, I've updated the answer with something that might be more what you're looking for.